# Nuxtjs [object Object] not found

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm playing around with Nuxtjs and the new @nuxt/content module for pulling in markdown blog posts.

```js
export default {
  watchQuery: true,
  async asyncData ({ $content, route }) {
    const q = route.query.q

    let query = $content('articles', { deep: true })
      .sortBy('date', 'desc')

    if (q) {
      query = query.search(q)
      // OR query = query.search('title', q)
    }

    const articles = await query.fetch()

    return {
      q,
      articles
    }
  },
  watch: {
    q () {
      this.$router.replace({ query: this.q ? { q: this.q } : undefined }).catch(() => { })
    }
  }
}
```

I've got the markdown files stored in /content/articles/_year/_month/ I'm getting an error of /articles/[object Object] not found and it seems to be a query error with asyncData().

When I remove { deep: true} the error goes away but of course it doesn't pull the content from the subdirectories.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of the content module are you using? [Deep fetch](https://github.com/nuxt/content/pull/63) was only merged 8 days ago. You need [v1.3.0](https://github.com/nuxt/content/releases/tag/v1.3.0)

Comment: @Phil amazing!!! thank you so much